# How to know if user prefers miles or kilometers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app I've got a certain distance in meters.

And I want to display it in kilometers if user prefers kilometers and display it in miles if user prefers miles. And in the first case I want to add to a string "kilometers" at the end and in the second one to add "miles".

What is the best way to achieve this goal?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not make it a user preference?

Comment: Read this [article](http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/11/localizing-iphone-apps-part-1.html) about iPhone locale. == Update == As the original link does not work anymore, [here is the cached version](https://web.archive.org/web/20130126031830/http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/11/localizing-iphone-apps-part-1.html).

Answer (score 16):

To determine whether the user uses metric or not, NSLocale can tell you:

```
- (BOOL)isMetric {
  return [[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem] boolValue];
}
```

Comment: Does `false` mean that miles are preferred?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk yes

Answer (score 6):

**Swift** equivalent of Chris' answer would be something like this:

```
func isMetric() -> Bool {
    return ((Locale.current as NSLocale).object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.usesMetricSystem) as? Bool) ?? true
}
```

Note that it defaults to `true` under certain circumstances. Change as needed.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, `Locale.current.usesMetricSystem` gives what the user would expect. But you don't need that if you use `Measurement` which handles it for you.

```
let distanceInMeters: Double = 2353.45

let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.unitStyle = .medium // adjust according to your need
let distance = Measurement(value: distanceInMeters, unit: UnitLength.meters)
formatter.string(from: distance)
```

The current locale dictates how it is presented to the user. To see how it works for different locales, try this in a Xcode Playground (examples are for UK and France):

```
let distanceInMeters: Double = 2353.45

let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.unitStyle = .medium // adjust according to your need
let distance = Measurement(value: distanceInMeters, unit: UnitLength.meters)

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_UK")
formatter.string(from: distance) // 1.462 mi
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_FR")
formatter.string(from: distance) // 2,353 km
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly you can't get the unit from `MeasurementFormatter` unless you parse the string (which will probably be buggy with some locales like "ar" that use special numbers). Note that for `en-UK` `formatter.string(from: UnitLength.meters)` will output `metres`, since it just "translates" the unit instead of converting it to the preferred one.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask the user whether they prefer miles or kilometers, in a preference or something. Then whenever you display a distance you would say.

In pseudo c code

```
function distance(meters) {
    if (userPrefersKM) {
        return meters / 1000 + " kilometers";
    else if (userPrefersMiles) {
        return meters / METERS_IN_A_MILE + " miles";
}
```

Where `METERS_IN_A_MILE` would be about 1600, but you should look that up.

Comment: 1609.344 meters in a mile

Answer (score 0):

Unless the iPhone provides this information directly, you'll have to have a lookup table from locale to default unit. Then you should allow the user to override that default.

Comment: It does provide it directly, see my answer :)